# Can we use present continuous when we talk about facts?

Tags: present-continuous

I know we should use *present simple* when we talk about facts, but can we use *present continuous* too?

I'm not sure if the following is a good example.

> Adaptations in the cow elephant seal allow the production of a highly nutritious milk to fuel rapid pup growth: by second week of lactation, the **cow is producing** milk with 40% fat content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not normal in UK or American English. I think it is very much more common in Indian English.

(It's hard to find statistics to bear this up: a search for "Cow is producing" in the GloWbE corpus produces only three instances; of these just has this "timeless" sense, and that one is from an Indian source.)

Comment: It's not uncommon to use the continuous when speaking of stages (of development, or of a process). *With growth and maturation, periods between eating are lengthened and more time is spent in wakeful activity. By nine months the infant **is eating** three major meals a day, with periodic snacks and sleeping approximately 10 hours at night.* (Psychosocial Components of Occupational Therapy. Ann Cronin Mosey. 1986)